# How do I solve the following issue in QUirks mode?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with a width 200px.It has a left and right padding of 100px each. In IE7,IE8 and firefox 4,it appends the padding to the elements width.However, In IE Quirks mode, the padding is not appended and the width remains 200px.How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#t1{float:left;border:#000 thin groove;width:200px;padding:10px 100px 10px 100px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<p id="t1">This is child 1</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not using quirks mode. Quirks mode uses a broken box model, so this is expected behavior of that rendering mode.

You're already using standards mode with a proper doctype declaration; what's causing quirks mode to be triggered on IE?